# Difficulties understanding MapKit Coordinate System

Tags: ios7, mapkit

I read the apple docs

> "A map point is an x and y value on the Mercator map projection" 
>   A point is a graphical unit associated with the coordinate system of a UIView

What is the difference logically between a Point and a MKPoint?
I obviously need CGPoint to display something on the screen.
So why does MapKit need MKMapPoint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that both the `CGPoint` and `MKMapPoint` structs happen to store two floating-point values named `x` and `y` is irrelevant.

They are given different names because they logically deal with different coordinate systems, transformations, ranges and scales.

A 2D world map needs a large, fixed coordinate system that allows a latitude and longitude to be converted to a *fixed* point on the map regardless of what *portion* is currently being displayed on the screen.

The range of `MKMapPoint` values are large since they need to represent the world's coordinates at a high-enough resolution (well beyond screen sizes).

However, you don't exactly need to care about the actual *values* of an `MKMapPoint`.  Occasionally, you may need to convert a `CLLocationCoordinate2D` to an `MKMapPoint` (or the other way around)  but you don't need to worry about those values nor should you store them (the docs recommend not doing this since the internal projection calculations to convert a latitude and longitude to a 2D projection may change between iOS releases).

Your usage of an `MKMapPoint` is only on the basis that you are dealing with the map's 2D projection *independent* of the device's screen size or what portion of the map is currently displaying.

> I obviously need CGPoint to display something on the screen.

Yes but when adding annotations or overlays, you generally deal with `CLLocationCoordinate2D` values and let the map view do the conversion as needed.

Answer (score 2):

MKMapPoint is a geographical point - projectively converted latitude and longitude. On the screen you have some bounded view containing your mapView. And you need to convert your geographical position (coord) to the CGPoint on your mapView

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D coord;
coord.latitude = location.latitude.doubleValue;
coord.longitude = location.longitude.doubleValue;

MKMapPoint point = MKMapPointForCoordinate(coord);

CGPoint cgpoint = [mapView convertCoordinate:coord toPointToView:mapView];
```

Comment: I conveted Latitude/Longitude (-68.062496 84.487590) to MKMapPoint= 83466652.564906 4613734.348645 and then CGPoint= 83466656.000000 4613734.500000. What puzzles me are besides from MKMapPoint beeing aprox CGPoint also the large value itself 83466656.00000. Shouldn't CGPoint be for example on a iPhone between 320 and 480?

Comment: CGPoint on map depends on the center of your map and its zoom. For example, you have a small piece gf map on screen with New-York in the center of it. Then geographical point of London will be far away in terms of screen coordinates (320,480).