# Zooming increases self.map.visibleMapRect.origin.x and y, but why?

Tags: ios, mkmapview, zooming

I have realized through testing that `MKMapView.visibleMapRect.origin.x` increases as you scroll the map in right (East) direction, and `MKMapView.visibleMapRect.origin.y` increases as you scroll down (South) direction (given that the North is UP).

My question is: Why would `MKMapView.visibleMapRect.origin.x` increase when you zoom in?

Isn't `MKMapView` origin the top left most point of the visible area? Then, wouldn't `MKMapView.visibleMapRect.origin.x` decrease as you zoom in, because the top left position is now lower on the map?

It makes sense that `MKMapView.visibleMapRect.origin.y` would increase because the visible area is now actually lower than before.

So why would `MKMapView.visibleMapRect.origin.x` increase when you zoom in? It shouldn't be!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The map view's `visibleMapRect` property is an `MKMapRect`.

`MKMapRect` defines a rectangle using `MKMapPoint` units.

The map's `MKMapPoint` grid system is a fixed set of points covering almost the whole world.

The origin is at the top-left and corresponds approximately to a real-word coordinate of 85° N, 180° W.

The x-axis goes from 0 (left/west-most) and *increases positively towards the right/east* to some very large number.

The y-axis goes from 0 (top/north-most) and *increases positively towards the bottom/south* to some very large number.

The `visibleMapRect` indicates which **portion** of the entire world's `MKMapRect` the map is currently showing.

So the origin of `visibleMapRect` is just the `MKMapPoint` in the entire world's `MKMapRect` that is currently showing at the top-left of the map view.

Suppose you are viewing the whole world.
The `visibleMapRect.origin` might be x=0, y=0.
When you zoom in, the new top-left point being viewed is further to the *right* of the previous top-left point.
When you go further to the right, the x-axis value increases.

Maybe this crude diagram will help:

```
                                    x-axis  
                 0 ----------------------------- positive --->   
                ________________________________________________  
          0    |                                                |  
          :    |                                                |  
          :    |      +=============================+           |  
  y-axis  :    |      |A                            |           |  
          :    |      |        +==========+         |           |  
          :    |      |        |B         |         |           |  
      positive |      |        |          |         |           |  
          :    |      |        +==========+         |           |  
          :    |      |                             |           |  
          :    |      +=============================+           |  
          v    |                                                |  
               |________________________________________________|
```

- The outer rectangle is the entire world's fixed `MKMapRect` (`MKMapRectWorld`).
- The first inner rectangle with top-left corner "A" is some initial `visibleMapRect`.  Its "A" might be something like x=5000, y=2000.
- The second inner rectangle with top-left corner "B" is some zoomed-in `visibleMapRect`.  Its "B" will have a higher x and a higher y.

By the way, you don't really need to be concerned about the *specific* `MKMapRect` or `MKMapPoint` *values* themselves.  The answer to this related question might also help: [Difficulties understanding MapKit Coordinate System](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21094369/difficulties-understanding-mapkit-coordinate-system).

Comment: Thanks so much. I had the map upside down XD and that was the problem! XDXD. Thanks so much ~